# Sending arguments to Python threads blocks other threads

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, python-3.x

Consider this test application for passing arguments to Python threads:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pprint import pprint
import signal
import sys
import threading


class CallThreads(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._target = target
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        target(*args)

def main(argv):
    phrases = ['hello', 'goodbye']
    num = 0

    for phrase in phrases:
        num += 1
        thread_handler = CallThreads(someFunction, phrase, num)
        thread_handler.daemon = True
        thread_handler.start()

    return True


def someFunction(a, b):
    print("Hi: "+str(a)+" and "+str(b))
    return True


def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print(["Got SIGINT!"])
    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    main(sys.argv)
```

In it's current state, it seems as though the `for phrase in phrases` loop is waiting for the thread to finish before starting another thread. That is, if `someFunction()` takes a long time to complete, then the then next thread will not start until the previous thread returns. Why is this, and how can I work around it while still sending arguments to the threads?

**Edit:**
I've tried saving the `args` array in `self._args` in the constructor, and then calling `self._target(*self._args)` or `self._target(self._args)` in `def run (self):`. This actually works in Python 2, but not in Python 3. What should I do?

**Edit:**
It seems that the problem is that in Python 3, the `run` method cannot access the private variables. That is, for the following improved code:

```
def __init__(self, target, *args):
    self._args = args
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    someFunction(*self._args)
```

Note the following output:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 639, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "./test.py", line 19, in run
    someFunction(*self._args)
TypeError: someFunction() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'
```

And adding a `pprint(self._args)` to the `run()` method indeed shows that the tuple returned is empty. However, changing the variables to non-private works! The following code runs fine:

```
def __init__(self, target, *args):
    self.target = target
    self.args = args
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    self.target(*self.args)
```

Therefore, I can use the application with public variables in Python 3. **However, is there any way to use private variables in the `CallThreads` class, as in Python 2?**

Thanks!

Comment: what is the purpose of this `CallThreads` class that inherits from `Thread`?

Comment: @qwwqwwq: The purpose is to facilitate sending arguments to the threads. In this case, the arguments are `phrase, num`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you call `target(args)` on the constructor of `CallThreads`.

Therefore the following call blocks until `CallThreads.__init__()` is finished:

```
thread_handler = CallThreads(someFunction, phrase, num)
```

**Update:**
One possibility could be the following:

```
class CallThreads(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._args   = args
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        someFunction(*self._args)
```

Comment: How to work around that? I've tried saving the `args` array in `self._args` in the constructor, and then calling `self._target(*self._args` in `def run (self):`. This actually works in Python 2, but not in Python 3. What should I do?

Comment: Find out why it doesn't work in Python 3. Normally that's what I do: pass the parameters to `__init__`, store them as instance variables, and define the `run()` method which will use these parameters.

Comment: Why instance variables? That would not let me call multiple threads with different arguments.

Comment: Interestingly, if I make the variables public then it works! Please see the Question edit. Thank you!